# Two views same URL

Tags: django

I have a single `dashboard_view URL` `path("", view=dashboard_view, name="dashboard")`.

On this page you can see the homepage unauthenticated. However, if you login, I present a modal popup to allow a user to populate a CreateForm.

The issue is that the `dashboard_view` doesn't have the form ( I have that in another view ). What is the best practice for this? Best for the user to have different options on the same page without having to switch pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `login_required` decorator. In login_required login_url is an optional parameter if you have declared the login path in the settings.py file. If your entire site has a login URL is the same. You can put `LOGIN_URL = 'login_form_url'`  in the settings.py file.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(login_url='/login_form_url/')
def dashboard_view(request):
    return render(request,'app_name/dashboard.html')
```